# How to make Discord Bot Automatically Role Someone when they have certain word in status

Tags: discord, discord.js, roles, status

trying to make it so if someone for example put my discord servers invite in their status ".gg/testing" it would give them a role and if they removed it would take their role away heres the code i have got right now off a similar stack overflow post heres my code right now but it doesnt give the user there role when they have .gg/testing in their status any tips?

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const roleID = "972823139119685712";

client.on("presenceUpdate", async (_, newPresence) => {
  const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
  const status = ".gg/testing";
  const member = newPresence.member;

  if (member.presence.activities[0].state?.includes(status)) {
    return newPresence.member.roles.add(role);
  } else {
    if (member.roles.cache.has(role)) {
      newPresence.member.roles.remove(role);
    }
  }
});
    
client.login("");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you're looking for. Credit to [HellCatVN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7180964/hellcatvn) whose code I edited a tiny bit to make this work.

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("941814488917766145");
    const member = newPresence.member
    const activities = member.presence.activities[0];
  
    if (activities && (activities.state.includes( ".gg/testing" ) || activities.state.includes("discord.gg/testing" ))) {
      return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
    } else {
      if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
        newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
      }
    }
})
```

The role will be gone if the user turns on invisible status too.

Comment: doesnt work still not giving me the role